# Sample size calculation for paired t-test single arm using r

Tags: r, t-test, statistical-power, paired-data

I am planning a study on alteration in AUC of a drug due to a surgery of gastrointestinal tract. It's a pre-post study. A group of patients will undergo blood sampling for AUC (area under curve) both before and after surgery. How can I calculate sample size using R?

Comment: If you only wanted to know how to do this in R, this question would be off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). However, I suspect there is a good deal of real statistical information that you may need. Eg, comparing AUCs is not generally the best approach & you wouldn't use a t-test to do it. Can you say more about your situation, your data & your goals?

Comment: my primary outcome will be to see if there is a significant difference in the exposure (AUC) to the drug post surgery when compared to the exposure before surgery. hence patients enrolled will be sampled 1 week before the surgery and 4 weeks after the surgery.

Comment: What does the AUC come from, a GLMM logistic regression?